# add simple form in plug in development

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have spent the last couple of days trying to find the solution to my problem with no success.
I have developed a plug in project based on section 5 of this tutorial:  http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html#ast_example.
So when i run the plug in project a new eclipse workspace is opened from which i can execute the program through the new menu choice i have added. But i would like to add a simple form so that the user can select one of let' s say three options and based on that option then continue with the rest of the execution of the program. Is that possible? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it' s 0%. What do i have to do? What does it mean? That it' s not of good quality?

Comment: Accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Click the check mark on the left to the answer you like to make sure it's green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be to contribute an Eclipse view with all possible options.

If you are not familiar with contributing to Eclipse views, probably the easiest way would be to open a JFace selection dialog (ListDialog) with all your options in your current command handler.

The code could look like this:

```java
Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(executionEvent);
ListDialog dlg = new ListDialog(shell);
dlg.setTitle("Options selection");
dlg.setMessage("Please select one of the options below:");
dlg.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
dlg.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
dlg.setInput(new Object[] {
    "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"
});
if (Window.OK == dlg.open() && dlg.getResult().length > 0) {
    Object selection = dlg.getResult()[0];
    // TODO decide what to do with selection
}
```